# Copy CSV with array of json into Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv

I want to use `COPY CSV` method to insert a csv file with array of json. I tried to look around in stack overflow but most of the methods are done through language like Python, I havent found the one using `COPY CSV`.

My Postgres table is this

```sql
CREATE TABLE individuals
(
  arr jsonb[]
)
```

My CSV is something like this

```
  arr
-------
{{"y":0, "x"; 0}}
```

And here is how I do the copy command:

```
cat 'file.csv' | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d testdb -U user -c "COPY individuals(arr) FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{{"y": 0, "x": 0}}"
DETAIL:  Unexpected array element.
```

Comment: The CSV would need to look like this: `"{""{\""x\"": 0, \""y\"": 0}""}"` - but what is the advantage of `jsonb[]` over a `jsonb`?

Comment: actually because It is array of json, I thought it should be `jsonb[]` instead of `jsonb` If the data type is `jsonb`, will the csv needs to look different than the one you have above?

Comment: A json array (rather than an array of JSON values) would need to look like this: `"[{""x"": 0, ""y"": 0}]"`

Comment: A json array is what I am looking for. But I understand that postgresql takes in curly braces `{` instead of brackets `[` as indicator of array.

Comment: If you truly want a json array, then `jsonb` is what you want (`jsonb[]` is an array of jsonb)

Comment: This gets a bit confusing to me. So if I want a json array (ie. an array containing multiple json objects) I have to use `jsonb`?
But if I want an array of jsonb (which seems to be an array of multiple json objects too), I have to use `jsonb[]` What is the main difference between those 2?

Comment: a json/jsonb array is a json value, and you'd store that in a json / jsonb column, a json[] or jsonb[] type refers to a PG array that is holding jsonb values. the jsonb values could be int, number, bool, null, string json-map or json-array. it doesn't usually make sense to have a type jsonb[] since jsonb can natively store the arrays. json arrays are enclosed in `[]`, postgresql arrays are enclosed in `{}`. If you can edit the source file, editing it as suggested by a_horse_with_no_name, to look like `"[{""x"": 0, ""y"": 0}]` is the best option IMO. also change the type from jsonb[] to jsonb.

Comment: Hi, all @a_horse_with_no_name and Haleemur Ali Thanks for your help and explanation. I decided to go with jsonb and it has helped to solve the problem for my use case. You can post answer here and I will mark it as the Answer.